# CORS policy unsolvable with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, cors

I have a website www.1.com which access to font on a subdomain sub.1.com
When I load the page, I have the famous "blocked by CORS policy, no access-control-allow-origin."

So, I add in the root of my subdomain a .htaccess with :

```
<FilesMatch ".(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)">
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

I tried with mod_header.c and other.
But none work !

What did I wrong ?
Thank you for your help, I know there is a lot of question regarding CORS, but I really do not understand what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to replace 'set' with 'add' and remove 'always'.

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
```

You could also set the headers in wordpress functions.php file like so

```
function add_cors_http_header(){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}
add_action('init','add_cors_http_header');
```

Both of these should get you taken care of.

Comment: Glad I could help!